# Can C++/CLI return abstract class from C++ to C#?

Tags: c++, interop, c++-cli

I've been reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx and found the part about defining abstract base classes very interesting.

Is it possible to have a C++/CLI class wrapping a C++ class return a pointer to a pure virtual base class (from a function in C++) to C#? I have quite a complex solution in the making but being able to return a pointer to an abstract class directly would simplify things a lot. The interface I would want to return a pointer to is structred like so (in C++)

```
class CCommsBase
{
virtual DWORD Init(char* info[], int amount, int id1, int id2) =0;
virtual DWORD GetJPVals(SJPV* jpv, DWORD timeoutMS=kiDONTOVERRIDE)=0;
virtual DWORD GetNums(int amount, int* out, DWORD timeoutMS=kiDONTOVERRIDE)=0;
virtual DWORD GetJPWinVal(SJP* jp, int id, DWORD stake, DWORD timeoutMS=kiDONTOVERRIDE)=0;
virtual DWORD Confirm(bool *bConfirmedWin, int id, DWORD timeoutMS=kiDONTOVERRIDE)=0;

virtual bool Connected()=0;
virtual LPWSTR GetErrorString(int errCode)=0;
};
```

The default parameters would have to be replaced for overloaded functions in C# of course, but this wouldn't be a problem. Is this even possible?

Thanks.

EDIT - should probably add, the arguments passed in as pointers are buffers that are filled with data inside of the functions.

Comment: I am not sure of what you want to do. Do you want to use a native C++ object from C# ? Or do you just need the pointer value as an integer and pass it around ? Could you write pseudo code of what you want to achieve (from the C# point of view).

Comment: Why do you want to pass a pointer to a pure virtual base class to C#? Wrapping with C++/Cli is not meant to work like this. The article just says "C++/Cli counterpart of a C# `abstract class` is `ref class XXX abstract... `"

Comment: The C# code has no use for a pointer to an abstract C++ class object.  Declaring abstract managed classes and returning *references* to them is certainly supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# can't call virtual methods from native classes directly. What you need to do is to write a managed C++/CLI class that mirrors the functionality of the native class and holds a pointer to it. It then delegates each call to one of its method to the corresponding unmanaged method.